# How do I print the output of the exec() function in python 3.5?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.5

How do I have it so that you pass in a python command to the exec() command, waits for completion, and print out the output of everything that just happened?

Many of the code out there uses StringIO, something that is not included in Python 3.5.

Comment: [StringIO is included in Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/io.html#io.StringIO)

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  [Exec just executes in place and returns nothing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec).  Your best bet would be to write the command into a script and execute it with [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) if you really want to catch all the output.

Here's an example for you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from sys import argv, executable
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
from subprocess import check_output

with NamedTemporaryFile(mode='w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(argv[1:]))
    file.write('\n')
    file.flush()

    output = check_output([executable, file.name])

    print('output from command: {}'.format(output))
```

And running it:

```
$ ./catchandrun.py 'print("hello world!")' 
output from command: b'hello world!\n'
$
```